# Error while inserting an item into the dataSource using kendo ui library

Tags: javascript, ajax, kendo-ui

I am trying to insert a new item into an existing kendo ui table but I get nothing displayed. DataSource is charged from an ajax request. Here in the definition of my kendo ui table

```
var baseUrl = '/SMART/api/Build/GetAll';
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: baseUrl,
                dataType: "json",

            },
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                    return {
                        models: kendo.stringify(options.models)
                    };
                }
            }
        },
        batch: true,
        pageSize: 15
    });

    $("#listGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        pageable: true,
        reorderable: true,
        resizable: true,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: {
            mode: "row"
        },
        columns: [

        {
            filterable: {
                cell: {
                    enabled: true,
                    showOperators: false,
                    operator: "contains"
                }
            },
            field: "Name",
            title: "Name"
        },
         {
             filterable: {
                 cell: {
                     enabled: true,
                     showOperators: false,
                     operator: "contains"
                 }
             },
             field: "Type",
             title: "Type"
         },{
            filterable: {
                cell: {
                    enabled: true,
                    showOperators: false,
                    operator: "contains"
                }
            },
            field: "ToBeDisplayed",
            title: "To be displayed",
            template: "<input name='ToBeDisplayed' type='checkbox' data-bind='checked: ToBeDisplayed' #= ToBeDisplayed ? checked='checked' : '' # class='build-tobedisplayed-checkbox'/>"
        },
        ]
    })
```

Here is the code of the insertion

```
 var grid = $("#listGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.dataSource.insert({ Name: "6.03", Type: "WIP", ToBeDisplayed: true });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is a simple one.

The `insert` command also requires an index position as part of the insert ie:

**this**

```
 grid.dataSource.insert({ Name: "6.03", Type: "WIP", ToBeDisplayed: true });
```

**would be**

```
 grid.dataSource.insert(1,{ Name: "6.03", Type: "WIP", ToBeDisplayed: true });
```

as per the documentation link. [datasource insert](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-insert)

if you want to add a new item to the datasource collection then use the `add` method instead.

[datasource add](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-add)